# Android TV app runs on mobile

Tags: java, android, android-tv

I want to create app that targets only Android TV. I use this in my manifest

`<uses-feature android:name="android.software.leanback"
        android:required="true" />`

considering on developers.android it says:

> If you set the required attribute value to true, your app will run only on devices that use the Leanback UI.

But i can run my app on any device(tablet, phone or TV). Am i doing something wrong? I also added activity with `android.intent.category.LEANBACK_LAUNCHER`.

Does this only happen in debug mode? And if so, does this allows me to test my TV app on devices like Android mini pc or Kindle Fire?

Comment: In addition to being more of a distribution control mechanism, it's not exactly clear that leanback is unique to TV's - the page about it appears to show a phone in the example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found that by setting  as you did, it limits the device compatibility on Google Play. But you can still test on other devices using adb (it works OK with 7 and 10 inch tablets, but the UI is too big for my Nexus 4). However, you can only launch through adb. The icon will not show up on non-Android TV devices even though it is installed.

Answer (score 1):

> Am i doing something wrong?

Not that I can see.

> Does this only happen in debug mode?

It happens when you are not distributing through a distribution channel like the Play Store. Quoting [the docs for `<uses-feature>`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-feature-element.html):

> The purpose of a  declaration is to inform any external entity of the set of hardware and software features on which your application depends.

Here, "external entity" primarily is a distribution channel, though in principle it could be anything else that has access to the APK and chooses to examine it.